# Getting exception using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper v7 thus, as per the online documentation I have found:

```
Mapper.Map(this, message, cfg => cfg.ConfigureMap().ForMember(m => m.Body, options => options.Ignore()));
```

The objects **this** and **message** being mapped exist and are ok. However I get this exception:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods...

Do I *have* to call `Mapper.Initialise()` first? The docs don't show it being called.

If so, how do I format the cfg parameter used above in the Initialize method (I tried it as-is, but Intellisense didn't approve...)

Thanks

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323889/automapper-mapping-a-list-of-ids-to-objects-in-many-to-many-scenario/52325460#52325460

Comment: @radders, Why didn't you mention your project type? Is it ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: It's a .NET Core 2.0

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md